# On scroll transform the element from bottom to center of the screen and remains center until the section's bottom touch the viewport's bottom

Tags: html, jquery, css, logic

I want to animate a element on scroll which is already tranlateY to 400% using CSS, now when the user scroll to that section it will come's up on **10% of scroll** and when it's reached to the center of page it remains center until the section has completed scrolled.

In this fiddle you can see the svg image code but it's not working properly i want both circle and svg animation at the same time i have commented the fiddle url

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    inViewport();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    inViewport();
});
function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset - $('section.section2').offset().top;
    };
function inViewport() {
    $('section.section2').each(function() {
        var divPos = $(this).offset().top;
        var divHeight = $(this).height() * 1.4;
        
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (divPos < topOfWindow + 50) {
            var scrolls = getCurrentScroll() / 4;
            $(this).find('.circle').css('width',scrolls+'%');
            $(this).find('.circle').css('height',scrolls*2+'%');
            $(this).find('.img-box').css('transform','translateY('+(topOfWindow / (15))+'%)');
        }
        if (divPos + 100 < topOfWindow ) { 
            $(this).find('.desc').css('transform','translateY('+(-topOfWindow / (10))+'%)');
            $(this).find('.img-box').css('transform','translateY('+(topOfWindow / (10))+'%)');
        }
            
    });
}
```

```css
section.section1{
    height:500px;
    width:100%
}
section.section2 {
    padding: 150px 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 170vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
section.section2 .circle{
    position: fixed;
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
    left: -50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -50%;
    margin:auto;
    background:#000;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transition:ease all 0.25s;
    margin:auto;
    z-index:-1
}
section.section2 .desc p {
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
    line-height: 1.563;
    text-align: center;
}
section.section2 .desc{
    transition: ease all 0.25s;    
}
section.section2 .img-box {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -110px;
    transition: ease all 0.25s;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform:translateY(400%);
}
section.section2 .img-box svg {
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section1">
    
</section>
<section class="section2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="desc">
            <p>This is dummy copy. It is not meant to be read. It has been placed here solely to demonstrate the look and feel of finished, typeset text. Only for show. He who searches for meaning here will be sorely disappointed. These words are here to the reader.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-box">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 195.8 190" viewBox="0 0 195.8 190">
                <path
                    d="m68.7 111.3v-35h3.5l16.3 29.2v-29.2h2.5v35h-3.5l-16.3-29v29zm40.3-23.9c-.4 1-.9 1.9-1.5 2.7-.6.7-1.4 1.3-2.4 1.8-.9.5-1.9.7-2.9.7s-2.1-.2-2.9-.7-1.8-1.2-2.3-1.8c-.7-.9-1.2-1.8-1.6-2.7-.4-1.1-.6-2.2-.6-3.4s.2-2.3.6-3.4c.4-.9.9-1.8 1.6-2.7.5-.8 1.4-1.4 2.3-1.8.9-.5 1.9-.6 2.9-.6 1.1 0 2.1.2 2.9.6.9.5 1.8 1.1 2.4 1.8.6.8 1.2 1.7 1.5 2.7.4 1.1.6 2.2.6 3.4s-.2 2.3-.6 3.4zm-13.4 12.9v-2.8h13.4v2.8zm2.2-16.3c0 2 .4 3.4 1.2 4.4.9 1 1.9 1.5 3.2 1.5s2.4-.5 3.2-1.6c.8-1 1.2-2.5 1.2-4.5s-.4-3.5-1.2-4.5c-.8-1.1-1.9-1.6-3.2-1.6s-2.4.5-3.1 1.5c-.8 1-1.2 2.5-1.2 4.4z"
                    fill="#fff" />
                <path d="m123.7 76.3v35h-3.8v-30.3c-2 1.8-4.3 3.6-6.2 5.3l-1.1-2.1 8.7-7.8z" fill="#fff" />
                <g fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10">
                    <path d="m0 85.8h36.3" />
                    <path d="m0 102.9h36.3" />
                    <path d="m159.5 85.8h36.3" />
                    <path d="m159.5 102.9h36.3" />
                </g>
                <g fill="#fff">
                    <path d="m162.8 96.6h1.6v-4.5c0-.2 0-.4 0-.4s-.1.2-.3.4l-.7.6-.6-.6 1.7-1.6h.9v6.2h1.5v.9h-4.1z" />
                    <path
                        d="m170.3 96.5c.2.1.6.2 1 .2 1.3 0 2-1.2 2.1-2.4-.3.4-.9.7-1.6.7-1.3 0-2.2-1-2.2-2.3 0-1.4.9-2.4 2.3-2.4 1.5 0 2.6 1.3 2.6 3.3 0 1.8-1 4-3.2 4-.5 0-.9-.1-1.4-.3zm3.2-3.3c0-.9-.7-1.9-1.6-1.9-.8 0-1.3.6-1.3 1.4 0 .9.5 1.5 1.4 1.5s1.5-.5 1.5-1z" />
                    <path
                        d="m178.3 96.5c.2.1.6.2 1 .2 1.3 0 2-1.2 2.1-2.4-.3.4-.9.7-1.6.7-1.3 0-2.2-1-2.2-2.3 0-1.4.9-2.4 2.3-2.4 1.5 0 2.6 1.3 2.6 3.3 0 1.8-1 4-3.2 4-.5 0-.9-.1-1.4-.3zm3.2-3.3c0-.9-.7-1.9-1.6-1.9-.8 0-1.3.6-1.3 1.4 0 .9.5 1.5 1.4 1.5.8 0 1.5-.5 1.5-1z" />
                    <path
                        d="m186.3 96.5c.2.1.6.2 1 .2 1.3 0 2-1.2 2.1-2.4-.3.4-.9.7-1.6.7-1.3 0-2.2-1-2.2-2.3 0-1.4.9-2.4 2.3-2.4 1.5 0 2.6 1.3 2.6 3.3 0 1.8-1 4-3.2 4-.5 0-.9-.1-1.4-.3zm3.2-3.3c0-.9-.7-1.9-1.6-1.9-.8 0-1.3.6-1.3 1.4 0 .9.5 1.5 1.4 1.5.8 0 1.5-.5 1.5-1z" />
                    <path d="m5.6 90.4h4.1v.9h-3.1v2.2h2.5v.9h-2.5v2.3h3.3v.9h-4.3z" />
                    <path
                        d="m13.3 95.9c.4.4 1.1.8 1.8.8s1.2-.4 1.2-1c0-1.6-3.4-1.2-3.4-3.4 0-1.2 1-2 2.3-2 .7 0 1.4.2 2 .7l-.4.8c-.4-.4-1-.6-1.6-.6-.7 0-1.3.4-1.3 1 0 1.5 3.4 1.1 3.4 3.4 0 1.1-.8 2-2.2 2-.8 0-1.7-.3-2.3-.9z" />
                    <path d="m22.3 91.3h-2.4v-.9h5.8v.9h-2.4v6.2h-1z" />
                    <path d="m28 96.5h1v1h-1z" />
                    <path d="m33.3 146 1.7 2-10.8 9.2-1.7-2z" />
                    <path
                        d="m39.3 152.9 2 1.7-1.2 9.7c-.1 1-.5 2.4-.5 2.4s.8-1.1 1.3-1.8l5.3-6.3 2 1.7-9.2 10.9-2-1.7 1.2-9.7c.1-1 .5-2.4.5-2.4s-.8 1.1-1.3 1.8l-5.3 6.2-2-1.7z" />
                    <path
                        d="m53.4 163.9 2.3 1.2.9 9.8c.1 1 0 2.5 0 2.5s.5-1.3.9-2l3.8-7.3 2.3 1.2-6.6 12.6-2.3-1.2-1-9.7c-.1-1 0-2.5 0-2.5s-.5 1.3-.9 2l-3.8 7.2-2.3-1.2z" />
                    <path
                        d="m75.8 173c4.2 1.1 6.3 4.9 5.3 8.9-1.1 4-4.8 6.4-9 5.3s-6.3-5-5.2-9.1c1-3.8 4.7-6.1 8.9-5.1zm-3.1 12c2.6.7 5.1-.9 5.8-3.7.7-2.7-.7-5.2-3.3-5.9s-5.1.9-5.8 3.5c-.7 2.7.6 5.4 3.3 6.1z" />
                    <path d="m86.3 175.5 2.8.1 2.7 9.4c.2.8.5 2.1.5 2.1s.3-1.2.6-2.1l3.6-9.1 2.7.1-5.7 14-2.7-.1z" />
                    <path
                        d="m106.6 175.2 2.7-.4 7 13.3-2.6.4-1.7-3.4-4.9.7-.7 3.8-2.6.4zm4.4 8-1.8-3.6c-.4-.8-.9-2.1-.9-2.1s-.1 1.4-.2 2.3l-.7 3.9z" />
                    <path d="m121.6 174.2-4.4 1.5-.7-2.1 11.3-3.8.7 2.1-4.4 1.5 3.8 11.4-2.4.8z" />
                    <path d="m132.4 167.5 2.3-1.2 6.5 12.6-2.3 1.2z" />
                    <path
                        d="m145.4 159.1c3.4-2.6 7.8-1.9 10.2 1.3 2.5 3.3 2.1 7.8-1.3 10.4s-7.8 1.9-10.3-1.5c-2.5-3.2-2-7.6 1.4-10.2zm7.5 9.8c2.2-1.7 2.4-4.6.6-6.9-1.7-2.2-4.5-2.7-6.7-1-2.2 1.6-2.4 4.5-.8 6.7 1.8 2.3 4.7 2.8 6.9 1.2z" />
                    <path
                        d="m155.2 151 1.6-2 9.7 1.1c1 .1 2.4.5 2.4.5s-1.1-.8-1.8-1.3l-6.3-5.2 1.6-2 10.9 9.1-1.6 2-9.7-1.1c-1-.1-2.4-.5-2.4-.5s1.1.8 1.8 1.3l6.3 5.2-1.6 2z" />
                    <path d="m23.1 39.1-2.9 3.7-1.8-1.4 7.3-9.4 1.8 1.4-2.8 3.6 9.4 7.4-1.6 2z" />
                    <path
                        d="m30.6 27 6.3-5.7 1.5 1.7-4.3 4 2.5 2.8 3.6-3.2 1.5 1.7-3.7 3.1 2.5 2.8 4.7-4.2 1.5 1.7-6.6 5.9z" />
                    <path
                        d="m48.5 13.2c1.6-1 3.6-1.5 5.5-1.1l-.1 2.3c-1.3-.2-2.9 0-4.1.7-2.7 1.6-2.9 4.4-1.5 6.6 1.4 2.3 4.1 3.5 6.7 1.9 1.3-.8 2.2-2.2 2.6-3.7l2.1.9c-.4 1.7-1.4 3.5-3.6 4.9-3.8 2.3-7.9 1-10.1-2.5-2.1-3.5-1.2-7.8 2.5-10z" />
                    <path
                        d="m60.3 7.4 2.4-.8 2 5.7 6.1-2.1-2-5.7 2.4-.8 4.7 13.3-2.4.8-1.9-5.6-6.1 2.1 1.9 5.6-2.4.8z" />
                    <path
                        d="m79.9 1.7 2.6-.3 6.3 7.5c.6.8 1.4 2.1 1.4 2.1s-.3-1.3-.4-2.2l-.9-8.1 2.5-.3 1.6 14-2.5.3-6.3-7.5c-.6-.8-1.4-2.1-1.4-2.1s.3 1.3.4 2.2l.9 8.1-2.6.3z" />
                    <path
                        d="m106.8.7c4.3.5 7 4 6.5 8-.5 4.2-3.8 7.1-8.1 6.6s-6.9-4-6.5-8.2c.5-4 3.8-6.9 8.1-6.4zm-1.3 12.3c2.7.3 4.9-1.7 5.2-4.5.3-2.7-1.4-5.1-4.1-5.4s-4.9 1.6-5.2 4.3c-.3 2.9 1.4 5.3 4.1 5.6z" />
                    <path d="m121.6 3.7 2.5.8-3.6 11.4 5.9 1.9-.7 2.1-8.3-2.6z" />
                    <path
                        d="m141.9 11.7c3.8 2.1 4.9 6.3 3 9.9-2 3.7-6.2 5.1-10 3s-4.9-6.4-2.9-10.1c1.9-3.5 6.1-4.9 9.9-2.8zm-6 10.8c2.4 1.3 5.2.3 6.5-2.2 1.3-2.4.6-5.2-1.8-6.5s-5.1-.4-6.5 2c-1.2 2.5-.6 5.4 1.8 6.7z" />
                    <path
                        d="m159.7 24.4c1.4 1.2 2.5 2.9 2.8 4.9l-2.2.6c-.1-1.2-.9-2.6-1.9-3.5-2.4-2.1-5.1-1.6-6.9.4-2 2.3-1.8 5.2.2 7 1 .9 2.3 1.3 3.6 1.3l1.1-1.2-1.6-1.4 1.5-1.7 3.4 3-5 5.6-1.6-1.5.5-.5c.2-.2.4-.4.4-.4-1.3.1-2.9-.5-4.1-1.6-2.8-2.5-3.3-6.8-.3-10.1 2.5-3.4 6.9-3.7 10.1-.9z" />
                    <path
                        d="m164.2 41.6 3.7-8.8 1.8 2.3-2 4.3c-.4.9-1 1.8-1 1.8s1.1-.3 2-.5l4.7-.8 1.8 2.3-9.4 1.2-4.7 3.6-1.6-2z" />
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="circle">

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4frbm2pk/1/

Comment: Add your code _within_ your question. Use the [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) button (7th from left) to add a runnable code snippet.

Comment: Hey hi @Turnip
I have added the code as per your request

Comment: Black circle is working fine when I scrolled down on full screen but it is merging with text sometimes